# 401 UnAuthorized Error with Service Account using EWS

Tags: service, authorization, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I had the Exchange Server Admins create an email account for me that I could use for EWS API testing (it was not an AD account). I used EWS api with no problem (using webCredentials).  This app that uses EWS API consumes information from a mailbox and does stuff with it.

Now we had a service account created that will be used for a service on a server running the application.  If I use the credentials for this service account (when I entered the credentials via WebCredentials) I get a 401 UnAuthorized.

I also used the EWSEditor and the same thing happens.

Any ideas about what I should be looking for or what to ask the AD/Exchange admins to check/change, etc?

Answer (score 0):

> > I had the Exchange Server Admins create an email account for me that I could use for EWS API testing (it was not an AD account)

So this is technically incorrect, eg there is no such thing as an email account with Exchange you have an AD Account and the administrator then creates a Mailbox that is associated with that Active Directory Account (so be careful with what the admins are telling you if they are saying there is no AD Account).

> > Now we had a service account created that will be used for a service on a server running the application. If I use the credentials for this service account (when I entered the credentials via WebCredentials) I get a 401 UnAuthorized.

Is the service account mail enabled ? the easiest thing to do is ask them to Mail Enable (create a Mailbox) for the service account (if they don't want it to appear in the GAL then tell them to hide it). You should then be able to logon and at least access the Mailbox of the service account as you where with you previous code or the ewsEditor. To then access the Target Mailboxes you want to access you just need to be assigned rights (Eg add-MailboxPermissions and wait 15 minutes for application).